# How did they replicate being under water in Ready Player One in the real world?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

In Ready Player One when the High Five are about to challenge for the second key `The Shinning`, there is a scene when 'H' gets knocked over by a wall of red liquid (blood). After taking a bit of a beating 'H' is held under for a few seconds and when she comes up she clearly gasps for a breath.

'H' gets held under at 2:05 to 2:07,

I can think of a few reasons as to why 'H' reacted like that if there was not a way of simulation being held under water and one reason could possible be that it was just a natural reaction to being put in that situation, being that the Virtual Reality is so real.

But that thought aside, was there anything in or out of universe that shows how they were able to replicate being held under water (blood)?

Comment: I don't know if there is a term for it, but I think you are on the right track. Sure, the VR is fake, but the OASIS is supposed to be so realistic that it is indistinguishable from real life with a fancy enough interface. In that moment I would say that Aech was so wrapped up in what was happening that her mind tricked her into thinking it was real and she didn't take the time to think about the fact it was all fake. Given the rigs in her van I am sure she was being flipped all over the place in real life and it would not be that hard to forget in that moment it was all fake and think it real.

Comment: Agreed, if you felt like you were underwater you'd probably hold your breath